Can a WebAssembly::Memory SharedArrayBuffer be read as a slice without copying?
I wish to write a library in Rust that will compile to both a DLL and to WASM. The library should be able to take a pointer to shared memory and update the contents of the memory. Here's a rough outline for how the JS interface will look:
test.js:
const shared_mem = new WebAssembly.Memory({
  initial: 1, // 1 page = 64k
  maximum: 1,
  shared: true,
});
write_to_shared_memory(shared_mem);
const val = read_from_shared_memory(shared_mem);

In order to support DLL compilation, I want the main implementation methods to use raw Rust types, rather than JsValue or other wasm-bindgen specific types. For example:
lib.rs:
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn write_to_shared_memory(mem: &WebAssembly::Memory) -> () {
    let ptr = ???;
    let mut_ref = unsafe { ??? };
    write_impl(mut_ref);
}

pub fn write_impl(mem: &mut [u8]) -> () {
    for i in 0..100 {
        mem[i] = i;
    }
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn read_from_shared_memory(mem: &WebAssembly::Memory) -> JsValue {
    let ptr = ???;
    let const_ref = unsafe { ??? };
    return read_impl(const_ref).into();
}

pub fn read_impl(arr: &[u8]) -> u8 {
    return arr[0];
}

The question is what would be the implementation of ??? in order to convert a &WebAssembly::Memory into a &mut [u8]? I imagine something like this should be possible (in a very unsafe way) using raw pointers and std::mem::transmute
Note: I know that this is very unsafe (there's no guarantees that the index I'm writing to is valid, there's a risk of data races, etc)... I am doing this for intellectual curiosity. This will not harm any production systems.

As I’m continuing to play with what Rust and WASM can do (I have very little experience using either) I’m learning some additional things. Like memory allocated by Rust can be directly accessed through wasm.memory.buffer. I gave this a try and found it was much faster than even shared memory, but had the drawback of memory management lying in my Rust code. Ideally (in a non-WASM world) I want my memory allocating methods to hand ownership of their memory to the caller. WASM doesn’t seem to have something like this, so I was looking into hacks like shared memory to avoid copying.

Generally update headers and information are irrelevant and should be avoided Your question has become very hard to read because of your addition. Can you rewrite it to appear like a single, coherent question?

Reading through it again, it almost seems your edit is actually an answer. In that case, you should revert your edit and add an actual answer post below.

As @cafce25 said, your question is unclear. Do you have a solution? Post it in an answer, not as an edit. Do you not? Make it clear what exactly is your problem, without a sequence of edits but as a single, coherent question.

The original question is unanswered and I remain interested in the answer out of academic curiosity. However the root issue I was trying to resolve has been addressed in a different way. I will update and clean up my question in the morning.
